# arules with quantity magnitude for each product

Tags: r, data-mining, arules, market-basket-analysis

I want to use the arules package of r for market basket analysis.

The issue is I do not have data for each transaction. My data is aggregated for every day. So I am thinking of comparing the quantity sold of each product.

How do I input this magnitude of quantity sold and use arules package with it?

Comment: This is difficult. arules currently only supports transactions weights via weclat().

Comment: @MichaelHahsler Can you please illustrate how to use weclat() for the same? Or is it that I can only give weights to transactions and not individual products? Thanks.

Comment: @PatrasMehta Correct, unfortunately only transaction weights are supported, but not item weights. I think the reason is that it is not clear how support of an itemset is defined, if each item has a different weight.